Reality Composer Pro geometry model to view transform for RealityKit is bogus
I have been trying to use the Geometry Modifier Model To View 4x4 transform matrix in shaders created by Reality Composer Pro, but my results always seem to yield zeros. As a simple test I created a shader that takes the determinant of the matrix and outputs it as a color, but it always yields black (0,0,0).

I thought maybe it only works in a RealityKit program, so I tried using the shader for shader graph material for a plane .. same result ...

Is this broken or not usable?
EDIT: Just to make sure the channels fed to the color input are in the range [0,1] I modified the shader as follows:

The constant input vector is (1,1,1). Still black. I guess no one uses this at Apple?
